# Code design: performance vs maintainability

Tags: java, testing, software-design

### Contextualisation

Im am implementing a bytecode instrumenter using the soot framework in a testing context and I want to know which design is better.

I am building the TraceMethod object for every Method in a Class that I am instrumenting and I want to run this instrumenter on multiple Classes.

Which Option offers more performance(Space–time)?

#### Option 1: (Maps)

```
public class TraceMethod {
    boolean[] decisionNodeList;
    boolean[] targetList;
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> dependenciesMap;
    Map<Integer,List<Double>> decisionNodeBranchDistance;
}
```

#### Option 2: (Objects)

```
public class TraceMethod {
    ArrayList<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>(); 
    ArrayList<DecisionNode> decisionNodes = new ArrayList<DecisionNode>();
}

public class DecisionNode {
    int id;
    Double branchDistance;
    boolean reached;
}

public class Target {
    int id;
    boolean reached;
    List<DecisionNode> dependencies;
}
```

I have implemented the *option 2* by myself, but my boss suggest me the *option 1* and he argue that is "lighter". I saw that in this article "[Class Object vs Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258071/class-object-vs-hashmap)" that HashMaps use more memory than Objects, but im still not convinced that my solution(*option 2*) is better.

Its a simple detail but i want to be sure that I am using the optimal solution, my concern is about performance(Space–time). I know that the second option are way better in term of maintainability but i can sacrifice that if its not optimal.

Comment: It's probably a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @JFPicard, im posting the question on  codereview.stackexchange.com. Should I delete my question here?

Comment: It's not only about Map or Object, you have entirely different data structures that allow / force you to access data in different ways. Accessing things by id is O(n) for `List<Thing>`  vs O(1) for `Map<Integer, Thing>`. wrt lighter: a typical Map is a 75% or less filled array[] of node-objects in a linked list structure, each holding onto the actual key and value objects. In this case (Lists of) Integer and Double objects. To me, 2 looks lighter because you have a list of objects that contain an `int` *plus* other stuff instead of a List that has just the `int` wrapped in an `Integer` object.

Comment: 99% of the time, the right answer is to write the code that is more readable and maintainable, and rewrite it if your performance measurements tell you it is a problem.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: You should avoid duplicate question, so I recommand you to delete this question ;)

Comment: @Brian Goetz In case of a byte code instrumenter it is a good idea to design for performance. This easily can speed up by a factor of 100.

Comment: @zapl Why do you talk about LinkedList, ArrayList has O(1) access, and a much lower prefactor that the amortized (not real!) O(1) of a map. This prefactro counts when having not an extremly high number of elements in his maps.

Comment: @JFPicard The [cross-post on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/99041/9357) has been closed since the question contains nothing but stub code. Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/9357) and take care to consider the criteria before recommending Code Review in the future.

Comment: Are the dependecies map dynamic or fixed? Can the made fixed arrays instead of ArrayList?

Comment: @AlexWien You misunderstood. Just space-wise, a `HashMap` is roughly an array of linked lists (`LinkedList<T>[]` - each list typically of size 1) (while an `ArrayList` is just a `T[]`) . The other part about O(1) vs O(n) is that a List<DecisionNode> does not allow O(1) access to the `DecisionNode` with `id=X` because you don't know it's index. The `Map` solution seems to allow exactly that, assuming the key is the index (and if not, wth is there a map needed?).

Comment: @AlexWien In the specific case of a bytecode instrumenter, it might be even better to use one of the many existing bytecode instrumentation libraries that already exist.

Comment: @brian, yes but maybe they have their reasons, E.g for special test code analysis, etc.

Comment: @BrianGoetz We are using the [soot](http://sable.github.io/soot/) library to instrument. That part of the code is the trace. It's meant to retrieve the data from the instrumenter and make the required calculations.
 In this case I am calculating the "fitness" of the "Targets" (every branch on the CFG) of the class to help guide the decision making of our evolutionary based search algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 has the potentical to be much faster and uses less space.

Especially for a byte code instrumenter, I would first implement approach 1.
And then when it works, replace both Lists with non generic lists that use primitive types instead of the Integer and Double object.

Note that an int needs 4 bytes while an Integer (Object) need 16 - 20 bytes, depending on the machine (16 at PC, 20 at android).

The List can be replaced with `GrowingIntArray` (I have found that in an statistic package of Apache if I remeber correctly) which uses primitive ints. (Or maybe just replaced by an int[] once you know that the content cannot change anymore)
Then you just write your own GrowingDoubleArray (or use double[])

Remember Collections are handy but slower.
Objects use 4 times more space than primitives.

A byte code instrumenter needs performance, it is not a software that is run once a week.

Finally I would not replace that Maps with non generic ones, that seems
 for me to much work. But you may try it as last step.

As a final optimization step: look how many elements are in your lists or maps. If that are usually less than 16 (you have to try that out), you may switch to a linear search,
which is the fastest, for a very low number of elements.
You even can make your code intelligent to switch the search algorithms once the number of elements exceed a specific number.
(Sun/Oracle java does this, and Apple/ios, to) in some of their Collections.
However this last step  will make you code much more complex.

Space as an exmample:
DecisionNode: 16 for the class + 4 (id) + 20 (Double) +4 (boolean) = 44  + 4 padding to then next multiple of 8 = 48 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: In both designs: why do you need a map? If your code creates the node ids, then you can use an ArrayList instead.  NodeId = postion in array. having an unbeatable direct access.

Comment: You asked me "Can the made fixed arrays instead of ArrayList?"
The answer is yes, the dependencies are fixed at the beginning, but what kind of fixed array do you suggest me to use?
Could be bidimensional primitive array?

**Previous**:
`Map<Integer,List<Integer>> dependenciesMap;`

**Now**:
`int[][] dependenciesMatrix = new int[AmountOfTargets][longerDependencieCount]; `

Here i'm loosing a lot of space on the second dimension, because I can have for exemple: 100 dependencies for a target and  2 for another. Do you think its worth use that matrix ?

Comment: I dont really need a map, its true. I will just use a ArrayList.
Thank you

Comment: No study java arrays first, a bidimensional javav array is not like in C. it is always an array of Objects, initiallay all null, so an array of null. each array entry has its own length, so elems[i].length may be 3, and elemens[i+1] elems maya be 100.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should *always* go for maintenance, and not for supposed performance. There are few good reasons for this:

- We tend to be fascinated by speed difference between array vs HashMap, but in real enterprise application these differences are not big enough to account in visible difference in application speed.
- Most common bottlenecks in application are in either database or network.
- JVM optimizes code to some extent

It is very unlikely that your application will have performance issues due to maintainable code. More likely case is your boss will run out of money when you will have millions lines of unmaintainable code .

Comment: "More likely case is your boss will run out of money when you will have millions lines of unmaintainable code." I couldn't agree more!!! 