# Store unknown amount of ints in array without arraylist or asking for amount of inputs

Tags: java, arrays

I'm curious as to how one would take an unknown amount of, let's just say ints of user input, and store them in an array? I know ArrayLists was designed for this, but let's say we can't use them nor can we ask the user of how many times they plan on entering inputs.

Comment: Simply do what ArrayList does, but do it on your own -- create an array of estimated size, and if more data space is required, create a new larger array, and move data into the new array.

Comment: Implement your own `ArrayList` object? Or just make a gargantuan array and then resize it after all input has been entered.

Comment: You can check the implementation of the ArrayList class, to see how the add method behaves.

Comment: `new int[Short.MAX_VALUE];` ;)

Comment: It'll be pretty inefficient, but you can start with an array of say size 5, then increment the size everytime you exceed it and copy over stuff to the new array. You can copy over using ```Arrays.copyOf()```.

Comment: OR you can follow the resizing scheme of ```HashMap```, where it doubles the size everytime you exceed it and copies over stuff to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class [ResizableDoubleArray](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ResizableDoubleArray.html) in one the Statistic Package of Appache Commons.

The nice thing is that it uses primitives, instead of objects. This needs much less memory (interesting for application with huge arrays.

Similar example:
[IntArrayList.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/util/)

They all work like ArrayList: if limit is reached, a new array is allocated which is e.g 30% larger. fast System.arraycopy is used to copy the array content to new array.

See also 
[Code design: performance vs maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816774/code-design-performance-vs-maintainability)